# Will a Ubuntu upgrade affect my Windows installation?

Tags: upgrade, windows

I am running Ubuntu and Windows on the same laptop, and if I upgrade Ubuntu, is there any chance that Windows might be overwritten, causing me to lose my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading Ubuntu will not affect Windows installation.

But upgrading Windows may overwrite grub. It can be easily restored though.